# Did Paul Dirac believe in multiple universes?

Tags: physics, biographical-details, theoretical-physics, cosmology

Prominent physicist Paul Dirac proposed a [hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_large_numbers_hypothesis) that said that constants and laws of physics would evolve with time into different constants and laws of nature.

This hypothesis was used by [Robert Dicke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_H._Dicke) to argue in favour of the anthropic principle and the existence of multiple universes each one with its own set of rules and laws.

Though Dicke modified Dirac's hypothesis, I have read that Dirac himself once said that 'Dicke's reasoning was sound'.

Does that mean that Dirac, like Dicke, considered the existence of multiple universes with their own set of rules?

Comment: Is your question "considered" or "believed in"?  My answers might be yes, no.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar What do you mean? Wouldn't it be the same?

Comment: I have considered many things I do not believe in.  Whenever I do a proof by contradiction, i consider something that turns out to be false.  Perhaps Dirac considered many different models for the universe, but believes in only one.